# Outlook Calender Event using Nodejs (ics, Nodemailer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, icalendar, nodemailer

This question is already asked here but no answer, [how to add outlook event using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75068171/15460455)

I am using **ics** and **Nodemailer** to send events to the clients using emails.

I am getting correct results on the gmail as expected [image: gmail]

But it is not working on the outlook, it just appears as the attachment and not added to the outlook calendar and says cannot import ics file.
[image: outlook]

I have searched the internet and the chatgpt but unable to find any solution.

**In short, I want to send calender events using Nodejs to the outlook and gmail. Right now I am using [ics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ics) library to create ics file and sends it using nodemailer**

**MY ICS FILE**

[image: ics file]

This is how I am sending,

```
const organizerMailOptions: MailOptions = {
      from: organizer.email,
      to: organizer.email,
      subject: `Event Created: ${title}`,
      html: organizerEventBodyTemplate(event),
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: "invite.ics",
          content: createdEvent as string,
          contentType: "text/calendar",
        },
      ],
    };
```

I am trying to add calendar events to the outlook and gmail via email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FOUND THE SOLUTION MYSELF**
It was a problem with the nodemailer attachment.

Just convert *attachments* to *icalEvent* and it will work fine.

Updated nodemailer part,

```
const attendeesMailOptions: MailOptions = {
  from: organizer.email,
  to: [...attendees.map((attendee) => attendee.email)],
  subject: title,
  html: attendeeEventBodyTemplate(event, organizer),
  icalEvent: {
    filename: "invite.ics",
    method: "request",
    content: createdEvent as string,
  },
};
```